# Net 7 Maui Null Reference Exception when updating ObservableCollection used in ListView

Tags: listview, nullreferenceexception, maui, .net-7.0

I am developing a Net7 Maui app and have encountered an issue when updating a ListView to display data. When I update the ObservableCollection that is bound to the ListView's ItemsSource, I get a null reference exception. This is happening on Android but not on Windows.
Here is a code example to reproduce the bug:

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ListViewBugSample.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Button
                x:Name="UpdateData"
                Text="Click me"
                Clicked="UpdateListViewData"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentData}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell ImageSource="{Binding Description}"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       Detail="{Binding Description}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using ListViewBugSample.ViewModels;

namespace ListViewBugSample;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private SomeDataViewModel _listViewModelData = new();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext= _listViewModelData;
    }

    private void UpdateListViewData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newData = new List<SomeData>
            {
                new() { Description = "NewData1", Name = "NewName1"},
                new() { Description = "NewData2", Name = "NewName2" },
                new() { Description = "NewData3", Name = "NewName3" } 
            }; 
        
        _listViewModelData.CurrentData.Clear();
        newData.ForEach(x => _listViewModelData.CurrentData.Add(x));
    }
}
```

SomeDataViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace ListViewBugSample.ViewModels
{
    public class SomeDataViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SomeData> CurrentData { get; set; }

        public SomeDataViewModel()
        {
            CurrentData = new ObservableCollection<SomeData>() {
                new() { Description = "Desc1", Name = "Name1"}, 
                new() { Description = "Desc2", Name = "Name2" },
                new() { Description = "Desc3", Name = "Name3" } };
        }
    }

    public class SomeData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When you run the app it will load the data the firt time, but when you hit the button and the collection is cleared and reloaded you will get the null reference exception.
I debugged the app and the issue is not when the clear is made or when the data is added, it seems to be something that happens when binds that new data.

**I found a work around for this issue:**
If you change the ListViewCachingStrategy to RecycleElement it will work fine, so it seems that the problem is when it tries to generate the cells for the second time but not sure.

I'm doing something wrong or this is a bug on MAUI?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentData}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <VerticalStackLayout>

                            <!--<ImageCell
                            Detail="{Binding Description}"
                            ImageSource="{Binding Description}"
                            Text="{Binding Name}" />-->
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: You may want to explain what you've changed and how that would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I tried Umesh Kamble solution of replacing the ImageCell for a ViewCell and it works fine, so the problems seems to be in the ImageCell with the default Caching Strategy.